# Machine Epsilon is not equal to $MachineEpsilon

Tags: numerics, machine-precision, arithmetic

I try to wrap my head around machine precision calculations in Mathematica (11.2, Linux). I do not understand the following behavior:

```
$MachineEpsilon
2.22045*10^-16

$MachinePrecision
15.9546

2^-46 // N
1.42109*10^-14

N[1 + 2^-46, $MachinePrecision] == 1
True
```

Why does this statement still evaluate to True? It is so far away from $MachineEpsilon that it should evaluate to False?

Furthermore, why does the following yield a result which is exactly equal to a mantissa of just 46bit? I guess its the same answer and the same question as above.

```
one = 1;
eps = 1;
SetPrecision[one, prec];
SetPrecision[eps, prec];
For[
 SetPrecision[eps = one, MachinePrecision],
 SetPrecision[one + eps, MachinePrecision] != 1,
SetPrecision[eps = eps/2, MachinePrecision]
]
eps

1/70368744177664
```

What I try to understand is what rules Mathematica applies that lead to such results. My problem is that currently I have the impression that I can't rely on SetPrecision[] etc.

Comment: Note that there is ``Internal`$EqualTolerance`` which controls the tolerance of `Equal`. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626748/590388

Comment: Thanks Alexey, that is exactly the background working logic I looked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. From the documentation of [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) (`==`):

> Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits).

(point 4 under Details)

You can use [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) (`===`) (note the `.` after the `1` to make it a machine precision number):

```
N[1 + 2^-46, $MachinePrecision] === 1.
(* False *)

N[1 + 2^-52, $MachinePrecision] === 1.
(* True *)
```

You can also look into `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` as pointed out in the comments. See the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983885/is-there-a-normal-equalq-function-in-mathematica/6626748#6626748) for more information.

Comment: Is there a reason for doing it that way?

Comment: @RobinGeyer So `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` will return `True`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7545025/6673902

Comment: In[60]:= {0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3, Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0}, 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3]}

Out[60]= {True, False}

Comment: OK, thanks, that makes sense. However, 7 Guard-Bits seems a little excessive ;-)

Comment: @RobinGeyer depends on your field. I mean the hard alternative would be to fully expose everyone to the full brutality of floating point numbers.